# rails gcloud deploy fails on App Engine Flexible Env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine

I have an app currently running on Google App Engine. For the past week or so I have not been able to run a successful deployment (this is after a few months of not having any problems). I get the following error while running `gcloud app deploy`...

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                                                                                         
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED
I, [2020-04-07T02:40:56.413717 #1]  INFO -- sentry: ** [Raven] Raven 2.12.0 ready to catch errors
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.6.4-p104), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: production
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:8080
bundler: failed to load command: rackup (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rackup)
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - tmp/pids/server.pid
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:133:in `initialize'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:133:in `open'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:133:in `write_pid'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:106:in `write_state'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/single.rb:103:in `run'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:186:in `run'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:73:in `run'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:148:in `start'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

I am running App Engine in Flexible Environment. My `app.yaml` is pretty standard.

```
entrypoint: bundle exec rackup --port $PORT
env: flex
runtime: ruby

runtime_config:
  dotenv_config: flex-env-config

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: $MY_INSTANCE
```

Running `bundle exec rackup --port 3000` locally produces no errors. I don't believe that this is a file permissions issue either, as I have formerly had no issue with creating these files on deployment. It also does not appear to be an issue with code, as I have rolled back my code to the last time I was able to successfully deploy an app and still receive the same error. The only thing that I can think of is that I have upgraded my mac to Mojave, but am not sure as to how/why that would affect anything.

Help/ideas appreciated!

## UPDATE:

I added a line to my bash deployment script that creates a `tmp/pids/server.pid` file and deploys this alongside the code (needs to happen every deployment because local rails server will delete this file on shutdown). I also added this file to my `.gitignore` as everything in /tmp directory is ignored by rails by default.

I am not happy with this solution, and I wish there were a better way to handle this situation. But it works, so hooray for that. Leaving this here in case anyone else runs into the same issue. Who knows, maybe Google support may actually respond, but I won't be holding my breath :)

Comment: This path `tmp/pids/server.pid` doesn't seem to belong to your project directory. Maybe it was not deployed with the app...?

Comment: @vitooh This is a file that Rails server creates automatically whenever it starts up. Not something that needs to be deployed alongside the app. Thanks though!